# How to wp_dequeue_script or wp_deregister_script jquery (not effected) file from wp theme

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, jquery-cycle, jquery-cycle2

**NOTE:** I already use `wp_dequeue_script` or `wp_deregister_script` but not successfull

Here is the scenario, i make a image slider plugin that use jquery-cycle2 and it work successfully.

There is a user who used a wp theme and in theme there is a `jquery-cycle1`, now when he install my plugin the jquery-cycle1 and jquery-cycle2 conflicts, when user delete the jquery-cycle1 file all things work fine and perfectly but i don't want to delete file by user.

Now i am trying that when user install my plugin the jquery-cycle1 in theme close or deregister or stop its effect.

I get file from theme successfully

```
if((file_exists($theme_file_path."/jquery.cycle.all.js"))){
    echo "yes";
}
```

but i have no idea to close jquery-cycle1 file or stop its effect.

**Last Option:** I have last solution that delete the file from theme but its my last option.

Please any suggestions, help me.

Comment: Can you paste the code from the theme where jQuery cycle is registered?

Comment: bro i don't know how the user call jquery in their theme

Comment: It's the cycle script in particular we're looking for. Do a search in the theme folder for the name of the js file.

Comment: yes i already do this .... and i am successfully get the file path and name

Comment: both the plugins uses the same variable name?

Comment: Sir you shouldn't delete / disable any files without letting your user know you do it. First of all you should display a warning that jquerycycle1 exists and it should be disabled and optionally display a link to remove/disable it.

Comment: can you explain how can i remove or disable the file.... please

Answer (score 4):

You will have to place an incompatibility notice on your theme.

It is not possible to attempt to detect the existence of script from server side.  You are able to detect queued scripts via the word press methods, however, this assumes that the user has not simply linked the file with a `<script></script>` tag.  The `file_exists` method assume the file is stored on the server itself - it could be linked from a CDN or another server.

Also, whatever methods you use to detect and remove `jQuery-Cycle`; You are going to break any feature on the site that uses the existing plugin.

Thus, any solution you able to devise would either be extremely complicated, or would not be generalised enough to account for all these possibilities.

You may be able to use the following to prevent loading your script

```
if (jQuery().cycle) {
   // Script already loaded
   console.log("Error: Another version of jQuery-Cycle is already loaded!");
} else {
   // Load your script
}
```

but this cannot unload what is already loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple hack you can do on you end. In the Cycle2 source replace all `$.fn.cycle` with `$.fn.cycle2` and `).cycle(` to `).cycle2(`.
I am using the source from here http://malsup.github.io/jquery.cycle2.js

After that You can access it like

```
$("#id").cycle2({option})
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/33g6z79h/

Here i assume that you are not using cycle events http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/api/#events
and cycle extra transitions.
If you are using it you can make a fiddle for your cycle2 implementation and i would be glad to help :)